# Mongoose populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

i am a quite new to mongoose and mongodb and have been trying to connect my user with a bunch of image posts. I read a lot about mongoose populate but i keep on getting empty images [].

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    images: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'Image'
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);
```

```js
const getOne = async (userId) => {

    let lastTenImages = await User.findById(userId).populate('images').lean();

     console.log(lastTenImages.images);

    // return lastTenImages
}
```

I also used mongoose.Types.ObjectId instead of Schema but still got the same result- an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should discard the id portion which is not working as the link to the User model. In other words try something like:

```
const imageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
})
```

I think that should populate the right array.

In addition, when you get the value you will be getting an array of objects. So you would need to map over it. `lastTenImages.images` won't produce anything.